# ignite: how to update trained model of decision tree with new data points

Tags: machine-learning, ignite

In the following way i try to update pre-trained decision tree model with new data points, but i'm getting a new model which is completely seems like a model which is build on new data points instead of combined version of trained model plus new data points?.

is anything i missed?.

```
// setup trainer
DecisionTreeClassificationTrainer trainer =
    new DecisionTreeClassificationTrainer(maxDepth, minImpurity);

DatasetBuilder<Integer, double[]> datasetBuilder = new CacheBasedDatasetBuilder<>(ignite, dataCache);

Model mdl = trainer.updateModel(
    (DecisionTreeNode) prevMdl,
    datasetBuilder,
    featureExtractor,
    labelExtractor
);

return mdl;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For now, the ML module doesn't support updates for decision trees. The problem in a tree structure, we don't come up good approach for branch delete during a model update.

Model update works well for other, non-tree-based algorithms.

Comment: understood, thanks. Can i expect implementation of update in next version of ignite?

Comment: For the moment , i'm re-building my model by combing old and new data.